# javascript, yet another TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function

Tags: javascript, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

I'm developing a web application (precisely it's a Tizen web application), I got that 'undefined' error although I already defined the callback function `serviceConnectionCallback`.

I'm new to javascript programming, hope you guys can help. Tks

Below is my code:

```
var serviceConnectionCallback = {
        onconnect : onconnectFromPhone ,
        onrequest : onRequest, 
        onerror : onerror
}

window.onload = function() {

    //do something...
    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", pageVisibilityHandler, false);

};


function pageVisibilityHandler() {
  if (document.hidden) {
    console.log("hidden");
    /*!!!!!!!!!!!!! PROBLEM HERE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*/
    webapis.sa.setServiceConnectionListener(serviceConnectionCallback);
  } else {
    console.log("visible");
  }
}
```

Comment: `setServiceConnectionListener` is not defined. Maybe you have to wait for `webapis` to load?

Comment: That's great, ***!!! PROBLEM HERE !!!***, and you're showing us a function call that according to the error is undefined, and you're not showing us the function, how should we know why it's undefined when it's not even in the posted code ?

Comment: Hi, I thought the 'undefined' is the callback `serviceConnectionCallback`, but like @Halcyon said above, maybe `webapis.sa` is not loaded yet. I'm trying to find out.

Comment: If `serviceConnectionCallback` was undefined you'd see the error on the line it is called (inside `webapis` code). On the line OP indicates `setServiceConnectionListener` is being called so that is the undefined function.

Answer (score 1):

When are you calling `pageVisibilityHandler()`? The flow that I am using to reach `setServiceConnectionListener` is as follows, starting from a `connect()` method;

```
1. request an agent: 
       webapis.sa.requestSAAgent(onSuccess, onError);
2. set up the agents in onSuccess: 
       SAAgent = agents[0];
       SAAgent.setPeerAgentFindListener(peerAgentFindCallback); 
       SAAgent.findPeerAgents();
3. set up the listeners:
       SAAgent.setServiceConnectionListener(serviceConnectionCallback);
       SAAgent.requestServiceConnection(peerAgent);
```

If you are skipping step 2, your local variable `SAAgent` is never instantiated and you will get an undefined error. SAAgent is a local variable which you should have initialised as `null` if you followed the guides.